# How to: Make ASP.net labels display dynamically on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net

How do I make ASP.net labels display *dynamically*, that is, they should not take up any whitespace when not being used.

I have a good chunk of error message labels at the bottom of a form, which are set to remain hidden until the user makes an error on one of the text boxes (does not pass validation).  This works, and they remain hidden; however, they still take up their respective white space, which causes the form to look goofy and unprofessional since there is a huge chunk of whitespace in the middle of the page.

I would like to make them appear, and only take up space, as needed, hopefully setting them to appear either in javascript or my vb.net codebehind.  Creative solutions are welcome.

Sorry if this is a google-it type question, I did make an earnest effort to find it online and my googlefu was not strong.

Comment: put the entire chunk of label in a div and hide the div, and show the div when validation fails

Comment: Hey, thanks Karthik.  I'm not sure if this makes the whitespace go away but is worth a shot.

Comment: sounds like you're using `visibility:hidden` in your CSS when you need `display:none`.

Comment: Right now I'm just doing $(ErrorLabel).hide(); for every label.

Comment: jQuery's `hide` function does the equivalent of `display:none`, in which case the elements should not still be present in the page flow. There must be something else preserving that space when the labels are hidden.

Comment: I just realized I have <br /> breaks in between each label.  How can I make the labels appear on different lines, while still eliminating the white space?  Can I make a return carriage a part of the text inside the label itself?

Comment: jBall had the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

A good control to use for validation messages is the validation summary control. In your code behind you can add your own errors as well as some automatic validations (i.e. required fields, etc)

Comment: Thanks Zdravko, I was not aware of this control.  Right now I'm using jQuery to show/hide each label, but maybe this is the way to go.  I have a lot of stuff going on in the code behind (server-side validation) and a lot of stuff going on in the page code (client-side javascript validation), so maybe this is the way to clean it up a bit.

Comment: The validation framework that ships with asp.net is quite powerful and is definitely worth looking into (especially if you are doing asp.net anyway). you'll find that you can do a lot of your validations in a simple and consistent way often with very little code.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way is to replace asp.net label with literal and wrap the literal with div. Then, you can hide or show the div. You won't need br tag.

Comment: Yep, this is one of the obvious solutions but is still a good one.  I think it's one of those things that I will have to put on my list to try out at least to see if it works.  Thanks for the reply.